# How to find the cell co ordinates of the button which was clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with all rows containing a button performing the same macro of inserting a row right above the button that was clicked. However, the code is not working as the macro does not insert a row above the button clicked but above wherever the active cell is present.

How should I modify the code so that the row is inserted right above the button that was clicked.

OR CAN ANYONE HELP AS TO HOW THE CO ORDINATES OF THE CLICKED BUTTON CAN BE IDENTIFIED.

```
Sub VBA_Tracker()

   Dim Origin As Range

   Set Origin = Sheet2.Cells(1, 1)

   Selection.EntireRow.Insert

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Include lines like this in your button code:

```
Sub Kommon()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    WhereAmI = sh.TopLeftCell.Address(0, 0)
    MsgBox Application.Caller & vbCrLf & WhereAmI
End Sub
```

For a "Forms-style" button:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Each Shape has a `TopLeftCell` property. It's the the top left corner of the shape resides. You could find the button row this way

```
a = button.TopLeftCell
```